# How can I only scrap new data with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, rss

I am working on a custom RSS feed generator, which scrapes a site and stores the scraped info in a JSON file, and then builds an RSS feed from the JSON. This would be run daily from a background process.

The site displays articles linearly, meaning the newer articles are before the older ones, and have a smaller page number.

Assuming the past data never changes, is there a way to only scrap new articles(i.e. stop when the rest data exist in the JSON)?

My current idea is

1. Load the JSON within the spider and check if the scraped item is already in it, but I am uncertain if the scrapping process is ordered.
2. Save the checkpoint manually such as the id of the most recent article, but I would prefer a more general solution that does not depend on data having a unique id.

Also, please let me know if there is a better way to implement this pipeline.

Comment: You could just use scrapy's pipeline for duplicates. When you're scraping the url and the same item is scraped then it will remove this and only return new data.